# Sort in order list using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Somehow I've managed the displaying of sorted order of colors upto some extent using Angular jS. But, as a whole its not working properly. Here is the code and fiddle. I'm trying to display in Green,blue, yellow & red order

Code

```
angular.module('MyModule', [])

.controller( 'MyController', function($scope){

$scope.redsFirst=[];
$scope.myArray = [
    {
        id: '123',
        color: 'red'
    },
    {
        id: '234',
        color: 'blue'
    },
    {
        id: '345',
        color: 'red'
    },
    {
        id: '456',
        color: 'yellow'
    },
    {
        id: '789',
        color: 'green'
    }
];

getSortedColors();
function getSortedColors() {
    var colorsOrder = [{color:'green'},{color:'blue'},{color:'yellow'},{color:'red'}]
  $scope.redsFirst=angular.copy($scope.myArray); 
  $scope.redsFirst.sort(function(a,b){
    return 1+colorsOrder.map(function(x){           
        return x.color; 
    }).indexOf(b.color)
  })
}
});
```

Fiddle :

```
http://jsfiddle.net/kjuemhua/4/
```

Comment: this can be done directly depending on what you need? Do you just need to generate colors in order, and do we have the option to set ids for them?

Comment: Just in that order list of colors which I've mentioned.

Comment: Do we have control over ids? As in, can we set ids based on the color if yes, why don't you list all of them in order directly using that.

Comment: I'm not bothered about id's. I'm just to put by colors order.

Comment: Can I set them in order directly for you directly using angularjs?

Comment: No. ID's can be anything. So, I shouldn't order by ID's. Order should happen only in color wise which I've put in the object. like green first, second blue, third yellow etc. I hope you understood my requirement.

Comment: please don't ask the same question more than once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759203/sort-by-color-wise-using-angular-js.  it's not really clear if this works and the other question is unnecessary, or if the people working to solve the other question will override this answer.

Comment: @Claies, yes how can I post it as duplicate of this one?

Comment: seriously? is this another duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758831/angular-js-sort-the-data-by-sequence-of-colors-images

Comment: delete the questions that aren't relevant, leaving them active as marked duplicates is will eventually cause them to be deleted anyway, and they aren't relevant since they contain the same exact code.

Comment: Please mark them as duplicate or let me know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please update your js file, same available at http://jsfiddle.net/kjuemhua/5/

```js
angular.module('MyModule', [])

.controller( 'MyController', function($scope){
    
    $scope.redsFirst=[];
    $scope.myArray = [
        {
            id: '123',
            color: 'red'
        },
        {
            id: '234',
            color: 'blue'
        },
        {
            id: '345',
            color: 'red'
        },
        {
            id: '456',
            color: 'yellow'
        },
        {
            id: '789',
            color: 'green'
        }
    ];

    getSortedColors();
    function getSortedColors() {
     var colorsOrder = [{color:'green'},{color:'blue'},{color:'yellow'},{color:'red'}]
      
      for(color in colorsOrder) {
       for(objColor in $scope.myArray)  {
          if(colorsOrder[color].color === $scope.myArray[objColor].color) {
           $scope.redsFirst.push($scope.myArray[objColor]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome sai. Can it be fine tuned?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to sort by color, answer is:

```
<div ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller='MyController'>
    <h1>Unsorted</h1>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='item in myArray'>{{item.color}} - {{item.id}}</li>
    </ul>
    <h1>Sorted by color</h1>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in redsFirst | orderBy: 'color'">{{item.color}} - {{item.id}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and in js file:

```
angular.module('MyModule', [])

.controller( 'MyController', function($scope){

    $scope.redsFirst=[];
    $scope.myArray = [
        {
            id: '123',
            color: 'red'
        },
        {
            id: '234',
            color: 'blue'
        },
        {
            id: '345',
            color: 'red'
        },
        {
            id: '456',
            color: 'yellow'
        },
        {
            id: '789',
            color: 'green'
        }
    ];
       $scope.redsFirst=angular.copy($scope.myArray);
});
```

Comment: What did you do? You didn't sort anything?

Comment: Actually I sorted the array based on color as
<li ng-repeat="item in redsFirst | orderBy: 'color'">
I guess the question was more about custom sort definition.

Comment: Yes. You need to sort in the order which I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution. You don't have to declare all colors in colorsOrder. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fzLwr921/

```
angular.module('MyModule', [])

.controller( 'MyController', function($scope){

    $scope.redsFirst=[];
    $scope.myArray = [
        {
            id: '123',
            color: 'red'
        },
        {
            id: '234',
            color: 'blue'
        },
        {
            id: '345',
            color: 'red'
        },
        {
            id: '456',
            color: 'yellow'
        },
        {
            id: '789',
            color: 'green'
        }
    ];

    getSortedColors();
    function getSortedColors() {
        var colorsOrder = [{color:'yellow'},{color:'red'}];
        $scope.redsFirst=angular.copy($scope.myArray).sort(function(a,b){
        var colorsMap = colorsOrder.map(function(x){ return x.color; });
        var indexA = 1+colorsMap.indexOf(a.color);
        var indexB = 1+colorsMap.indexOf(b.color);
        if( indexA*indexB === 0)
            return indexB - indexA;
        else
            return indexA - indexB;
      })
    };
});
```

Comment: Thx Egan. It's working too. Appreciate for the answer.

Comment: @Syed There is a small difference between my answer and saikumar's, as in my solution output array contains all objects from input array, no matter how many objects you define in `colorsOrder`.

Comment: Both answers are correct, but they return different outputs. It depends on what you need and how you want to use it.

Comment: I guess both return different outputs. Can you tell me exactly whats the difference in outputs?

Comment: @Syed In saikumar's solution, if you delete `blue` color from `colorsOrder` object, there will be no `blue` color in sorted array. In my solution it will be at the end of array.

Comment: Ah understood now. Thx Egan for your much effort to explain. Kudos!